# Change String with Sed

Tags: sed

I would like to change the following string

```
allow ^120\.123\.178\.254$
```

into

```
allow ^124\.130\.23\.235$
```

with sed.

I tried the following but it does not work.

```
sed -e 's/allow ^120\.123\.178\.254$/allow ^124\.130\.23\.235$/g' /etc/xxx/file.conf
```

May you can help me?

Comment: You might want to use `-r` for different escaping rules. You will still need to escape the backslashes themselves though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your source has `\`, `$`, `^` and `.` characters in them, which will need additional quoting.  Also your target has `\` which should be quoted

So the resulting string is a little messy:

```
sed 's/allow \^120\\\.123\\\.178\\\.254\$/allow ^124\\.130\\.23\\.235$/'
```

The final `g` you had is only necessary if this string may appear multiple times per line.

For example:

```
$ cat x
allow ^120\.123\.178\.254$
$ sed 's/allow \^120\\\.123\\\.178\\\.254\$/allow ^124\\.130\\.23\\.235$/' x 
allow ^124\.130\.23\.235$
```

Answer (score 1):

If `perl` is an option, both the search pattern and replacement can be quoted

```
$ cat file.conf
allow ^120\.123\.178\.254$

$ perl -pe 's/\Qallow ^120\.123\.178\.254$/q(allow ^124\.130\.23\.235$)/e' file.conf
allow ^124\.130\.23\.235$
```